# getting the count of titles opened by a user only if the first entry also belongs to the same user

Tags: python, django, database, orm

Title model:

```
class Title(models.Model):
    first_author = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150, unique = True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title_url= models.CharField(max_length = 150)
```

Entry model:

```
    class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey("titles.title", on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.user", on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000,)
```

In my blog, when a user opens a title the user also has to write the first entry (lowest created_date). When the first entry is deleted if there are no other entries in the title, the title also get deleted. So I want to count titles opened by the user only if the first entry of the title still belongs to the same user.

The only idea I have is to get all the titles opened by the user:

```
titles= Title.objects.filter(first_author=user.username)
```

Then iterate over titles and check whether the first title still belongs to the same user and if so add it to the count.

But since it requires iterating over the queryset the query object is no longer lazy and it takes too much time end effort.

I wonder if there is a way of achieving it by only one ORM.

Comment: The first entry is the one with the lowest `created_date`?

Comment: Yes it is that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check this with a subquery, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, Q

titles = Title.object.annotate(
    first_entry=Subquery(Entry.objects.filter(
        title=OuterRef('pk')
    ).order_by('created_date').values('user')[:1]
    )
).filter(
    first_author=user.username,
    first_entry=user
)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Williem, but this one returns an empty queryset.

Comment: `first_author=user.username` can never be true :)

Comment: Well the first_author is not a foreign key, so I think it can be true. The way I save titles ---  newTitle= Title(title=title,first_author=request.user.username,title_url=url)

Comment: @mattarello: edited, but it looks like a serious antipattern not to use an fk.

Comment: thank you a lot for your help, the final solution worked perfectly.